# What are the key differences between the Canon 60D and Canon 600D?

Tags: canon, equipment-recommendation, canon-60d

What are the key differences between the Canon 60D and Canon 600D?

I know the size is different and they are constructed of different materials, but in technical specifications and image quality, what are the differences.

Which one would you buy, considering the price difference is relatively narrow?

Comment: For more than a month iam comparing but there is no comparison at all.nothing makes me think about the 600d.finally i will buy the 60d without thinking

Answer (score 18):

**There is rarely a difference in image quality among such cameras**, from entry-level to mid-range, they often use the same sensors. It is a common misconception that DSLRs differ in image quality based on price, at least not until larger sensors are used.

**The most important difference is speed of operation.** The 60D has dual control dials and more external buttons, this lets you operate the camera and get the shot you want faster, with less trips through the menu system. **The viewfinder is also larger** which makes it easy to compose and check focus.

Second to that is speed, the 60D itself responds and shoots faster than the 600D. Thirdly, the 60D should be much more durable. If you actively take a lot of photos, the 60D can last longer.

To answer the last part, between these two, I would get the 60D without hesitating.

**EDIT:**
If the technical differences you are search are *specifications*, you can [easily compare them side-by-side](http://www.neocamera.com/camera_compare.php?model%5B%5D=190&model%5B%5D=318&compare=). The major differences are highlighted for you. As you can see, there is not much more than speed and ergonomics (viewfinder/controls).

Comment: The controls alone would be enough for me. I could never use those Rebel controls very quickly compared to xxD / xD.

Comment: On top of those you have mentioned, it is also worth mentioning that the 60D has better battery life, weather sealing, penta-prism viewfinder (vs 600D penta-mirror), higher fps, more custom functions, top LCD (for speed and better battery life) and better ergonomics.

Answer (score 18):

First note the ergonomics differences (from dpreview):

60D on the right here

[image]

600D on the left here

[image]

On the 600D you got buttons instead of a dial which is *less* useful and the mode selection knob is on the right next to the shutter button which makes it more cumbersome to use given that you have 2 hands to work with.  That and there are just fewer buttons to interact w/the camera and functions on the 600D.

Other differences:

**Viewfinder** 600D:mirror, 60D:prism (brighter viewfinder)

**Shoot speed** 600D:3.7FPS, 60D 5.3fps

**Custom functions** 600D: 34 settings, 60D: 59 settings

**Spot metering** 600D: 4%, 60D 2.8%

**Exposure comp** 600D:2EV, 60D:5EV

And the list goes on.  The 60D gives you more options and more/finer control.  Provided these things matter to you (and you have the means), the 60D is the one to buy.

These findings can mostly be generalized to any Rebel (X00D/X000D) class body vs a prosumer X0D class body.

Comment: A bunch of good points here. Allow me also to emphasize the ergonomics point. I shoot almost exclusively in manual mode, and would be miserable without two dials (and thus would take the 60D, even if for no other reason), *however*, I've known folks to feel that an XXD-series camera felt too big for their small hands, and they much preferred the XXXD-series cameras; when deciding between cameras, it really really helps to try each one in your own hands, and see how they feel. The 600D I'm sure would be "better" for some, because of size and shape considerations.

Comment: Now, I just don't get that at all. I have itty-bitty hands (really, I feel inadequate sometimes shaking hands, and it's incredibly difficult to buy gloves) and I never feel comfortable without adding a vertical grip (or, in the old days, a motor drive/autowinder). Perhaps it's my pianistic finger-spread, but I just can't seem to get a decent purchase on tiny camerae.

Comment: I'm also a big fan of using a full body DSLR. For some reason, they just don't seem to balance well with heavy lenses when they're only single grip bodies. I used a battery grip with my 50D and didn't hesitate when buying my 60D. I don't even have that big hands.

Answer (score 3):

The biggest difference is going to be in the build quality, as mentioned in the question.

The 60D is a mid range "Prosumer" model, while the 600D is targeted at hobbyists.

Here is a good [comparison from snapsort.com](http://snapsort.com/compare/Canon-600d-vs-Canon_EOS_60D).

Summary

> Reasons to consider the Canon 600D
>
> - Around 20% smaller
> - More than 30% lighter
>
> Reasons to consider the Canon 60D
>
> - Has a pentaprism viewfinder
> - More than 20% larger viewfinder
> - More than 40% faster continuous shooting
> - 2x faster max shutter speed

The decision of which to buy is very subjective.  If it weren't, then they wouldn't produce different models. :)

Answer (score 2):

Late answer here, but I recently got a 60D after spending months comparing it to the T3i (600D), and here's what I ended up taking into account:

Points in favour of the 60D:

- Better controls.  I find the dual dials and the buttons much easier to work with.  Having the small LCD display of critical settings is very handy and as most reviews and answers here have mentioned, you rarely need to use the main LCD for settings.  Also, I find it convenient sometimes to use the camera as a point and shoot, and I like the fact that the 60D has only a few automatic modes are they're simple to use.
- Faster - faster continuous shooting, faster shutter speeds.  It seemed a bit faster to turn on and shoot, but I'm not sure that's a significant difference.
- More durable - not as heavy-duty as a 7D, but the 60D is said to have some sealing, and is built a bit more durably than the T3i
- Better battery - I never checked the specs, but I was told that the battery on the 60D is much higher capacity.  It was really nice on a recent vacation not to have to worry about charging it, there's no problem taking tons of pictures all day for a few days between charges.
- Larger - I'm putting this as a plus for the 60D because I found it easier to hold on to, and so does my wife.
- Looks better.  This is obviously totally subjective and superficial, but I prefer the more professional look of the 60D.
- I think of the better viewfinder and AF system as being benefits down the road, features that will make the camera less limiting in the future.

Points in favour of the T3i:

- Cheaper than 60D (at the time I got the 60D, the T3i would've been about $300 less)
- Smaller, lighter than the 60D (but not that much lighter if you stick an 18-200 lens on it, which is what started with)
- Has more options for crop-mode (digital zoom) movies, 60D can only do 640x480.

So for me, the main things were the better controls, better battery, and better durability of the 60D.  I'm very happy with it and despite the larger size and weight, [I carry it with me almost everywhere.](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/16061/will-i-damage-my-camera-carrying-it-everywhere)